# Sollte man "vor" oder "bis" benutzen, wenn man über Zeit spricht?

Tags: preposition, time

Ich will auf Deutsch  den Satz " it is quarter till seven" sagen. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob "vor" oder "bis" besser dem Wort "till" auf Englisch entsprechen. Die zwei Möglichkeiten, an die ich denke, sind:

> 1. Viertel vor sieben
> 2. Viertel bis sieben

Danke fur Eure Hilfe.

Comment: In English it is "quarter to seven". Your question is answered by a simple dictionary

Comment: I don't think it's only quarter to seven [see this site](https://www.k5learning.com/docs/k5-learning-clock-sample-half-and-quarter-hours.pdf) for eg, there are many places

Comment: Wer immer diese Frage abwertet, sollte mal darüber nachdenken, was eigentlich Sinn und Zweck dieser Seite ist!

Comment: @Buraian: "A quarter till" is possible in English, but I don't know where it would be used now. (Wiktionary says India.)

Answer (score 5):

Richtig ist

> viertel vor sieben.

“Viertel bis sieben” ist mir nicht bekannt, ich würde empfehlen, es nicht zu benutzen, siehe aber die Kommentare.

In einigen Gegenden nennt man diese Uhrzeit

> dreiviertel sieben.

Comment: "richtig ist", daß Uhrzeiten regional verschieden bezeichnet werden und keine davon "richtiger" oder "falscher" ist als eine andere. "dreiviertel sieben" ist mindestens genauso "richtig" wie "viertel vor sieben".

Comment: @bakunin, offensichtlich. Jedoch würde ich "bis" als falsch bezeichnen, und danach war gefragt. Ich sage auch normalerweise "dreiviertel". Andererseits ist "viertel vor" problemlos auch für die verständlich, die es nicht benutzen.

Comment: Da hast Du recht. Noch schlimmer wird es bei 15min nach der vollen Stunde. zB 19:15 Uhr wird wahlweise mit "viertel acht", "viertel nach sieben", "viertel über sieben", "neunzehn Uhr fünfzehn" oder auch nur "viertel nach" bezeichnet. Siehe etwa Attwengers Lied "Hoiba Ochte".

Comment: @bakunin, finde ich auch, viertel sieben kann man wahrscheinlich eher als Viertel nach sieben missverstehen.

Comment: Viertel als Viertel vor sieben muss man groß schreiben.

Comment: Der [Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/uhrzeit/) nennt einige Varianten bei der Bezeichnung angebrochener Stunden mit ihrer regionalen Verbreitung. Interessanterweise gab es ein "20 bis 8" für _7.40 Uhr_ zum Zeitpunkt der Befragung (2012) noch in Teilen des Elsass und Lothringens, wo der Gebrauch des Deutschen allerdings stark schwindet. Leider ist 7.45 Uhr nicht dabei. Unerklärlicherweise gibt es jedoch für die parallel durchgeführte [Befragung zu 10.15 Uhr](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f11e/) keine Rückmeldung aus dem Elsass.

Comment: @RalfJoerres, interessant, Danke.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering in English because part, if not most, of the problem is in the English half of the translation: there are multiple meanings of "till/until", and these meanings have different translations in German. The "till" in "a quarter to seven" means "before"; the time is a quarter hour before seven. In the sense "before", you can translate "till" as *vor*. You can also use "till" in the sense "up until", as in "I worked till dawn." In that case "till" would be translated as *bis*. (You sometimes need to add another preposition to *bis*, so it might be *bis zu*. That's a separate issue though.)